# Display Published Date from YouTube Video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

[UPDATED]
I have two HTML pages i.e. index.html and player.html. On index.html, I have loaded multiple playlists so that when the user clicks on any video it opens player.html in a new tab and load the video in YouTube Player.

The problem is that on player.html, I have succeed to get the Video Title in a div but I am not sure how can I add Published Date and Category Name.

I am getting the following errors in Console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)

at window.onload (player.html?vid=Un5SEJ8MyPc:50)

each @ jquery.min.js:2

window.onload @ player.html?vid=Un5SEJ8MyPc:50

load (async)

(anonymous) @ player.html?vid=Un5SEJ8MyPc:28

Here is my HTMLs:

index.html

```
<section id="programs">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h3>Banking</h3>
            <div id="youtube-playlist-feed_1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Sponsors</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section id="programs">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h3>Business</h3>
            <div id="youtube-playlist-feed_2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

player.html

```
<div id="vtitle"></div>
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="published"></div>
<div id="category"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {
                var url = document.location.href,
                    params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
                    data = {}, tmp;
                for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
                     tmp = params[i].split('=');
                     data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
                }   
                 var videoId = data.vid;
                 var output = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'"></iframe>';
                 document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = output;

                 var id = videoId;
                 var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id;

                 $.getJSON('https://noembed.com/embed',
                 {format: 'json', url: url}, function (data) {
                 document.getElementById('vtitle').innerHTML=(data.title);


            });

                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                      console.log(item)
                  var videoID = item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
                  var title = item['snippet']['title'];
                  var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoID;
                  var output = 'Hi';

                  document.getElementById('published').innerHTML = output;
                  });
            }

            </script>
```

script.js

```
            var htmlString = "";
            var apiKey = 'AIzaSyA7dAzzNvPCxTSsSGiV7dvoj3rkt0qbdXg';
            var playlistID = 'PLBhKKjnUR0XBVrHvtDOylN5XREHh9X1nt';
            var maxResults = 7;

            var playlists = [{
                playlistId: 'PLJYHm_ZxWCKnQmapkDs7x47jkr-nw3l50',
                el: '#youtube-playlist-feed_1'
              },
              {
                playlistId: 'PLJYHm_ZxWCKmIBkoopKFK4kTTOmC1Zof0',
                el: '#youtube-playlist-feed_2'
              },
              {
                playlistId: 'PLBhKKjnUR0XAM2Wvi7JY5gLRpFLzIE-An',
                el: '#youtube-playlist-feed_3'
              }
            ];

            playlists.forEach(function(playlist) {
              getVideoFeedByPlaylistId(playlist.playlistId, playlist.el);
            })

            function getVideoFeedByPlaylistId(playlistId, el) {
              $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=' + apiKey + '&playlistId=' + playlistId + '&part=snippet&maxResults=' + (maxResults > 3 ? 3 : maxResults), function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                  var videoID = item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
                  var title = item['snippet']['title'];
                  var videoURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoID + '&list=' + playlistID + '&index=1';
                  htmlString += '<div class="video-wrap"><div class="video"><a target="_blank" href="player.html?vid='+videoID+'" ><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + videoID + '/mqdefault.jpg"></a></div>' + '<div class="title"><a target="_blank" id="player" href="player.html?vid='+videoID+'">' + title + '</a></div></div>';


                });
                $(el).html(htmlString);

                htmlString = '';
              });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`snippet.publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt) to show the date and time that the video was published. Also check the [`snippet.categoryId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.categoryId) to get the YouTube [video category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) associated with the video. You must set a value for this property if you call the **videos.update** method and are updating the [snippet](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet) part of a video resource.

Comment: That's what I am trying to use but I am unable to achieve the result. Can you please take a look and give me an idea what exactly I should do?

Comment: Anyone that could help? :(

Answer (score 0):

[This is what the JSON response is like (Click the link to see).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8SB8.png)

Just like the way you get "videoID" and "title", you can get the published date by

```
var publishedAt = item['snippet']['publishedAt'];
```

Comment: If I am putting this code in my Script.js, and accessing <div> id of 'published' by using document.getElementById('published').innerHTML = output;

it's giving me the title of 1st video of the playlist while I want the title of the youtube video which was clicked. Also, after putting this code in script.js, my index page is not loading the playlist and giving me the error below:

Comment: script.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (script.js:33)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (script.js:26)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:5)

Comment: Scenario is that on index page I have my Playlist loaded already when the user clicks on any video it redirects to player.html and load the video in the YouTube Player, I want THAT video Published Date and the Playlist name it belongs to.